# C# threading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C#,  when I am trying to connect to destination of my message queue, and having "catch(Exception e)",  I will have the following errors:

```
Name:e  
Value: {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.} 
Type: System.Exception {System.Threading.ThreadAbortException}
```

My main thread is  2228,  and  worker thread is 11104.

(
I think I have already successfully connected to my "message queue broker",  and created a "session",  now I am trying to get the destination -- queue in this broker.
)

Anyone has a clue where I should start to debug?

Comment: Always start writing code *without* catch-em-all exception handling.  You'll learn what mishaps you *really* can handle.  Seeing your code trying to handle a thread abort is a bit like Jack Nicholson's movie line, "You can't handle the truth!"

Answer (score 0):

This message is emitted by the debugger. It does not affect your programs behavior. It is a problem just because it hinders your debugging efforts.

Sometimes, restarting the process to be debugged helps.

What will work in any case is to write to the console:

```
Debug.WriteLine(a);
```

Look into the Visual Studio Output Window.